# Spherical coordinate to find $(x^2+y^2)dV$, Where $E$ is the regin bounded between $2$ sphere.

Tags: multivariable-calculus

> Use spherical coordinates. Evaluate triple integral $(x^2+y^2)dV$, where $E$ lies between the spheres $x^2+y^2+z^2=9$ and $x^2+y^2+z^2=16$ and $x,z\geq 0$

What i try:: Put $x=\rho\sin \phi \cos \theta$ and

$y=\rho\sin\phi\sin\theta$ and $z=\rho\cos \phi$

So $x^2+y^2=\rho\sin^2\phi$

And here $x^2+y^2+z^2=8\Longrightarrow \rho=3$

And $x^2+y^2+z^2=16\Longrightarrow \rho =4$

And here $\displaystyle z\geq 0\Longrightarrow \rho \cos \phi \geq 0\Longrightarrow 0<=\phi<=\frac{\pi}{2} $

$\displaystyle x\geq 0\Longrightarrow \rho\sin\phi\cos\theta\geq 0\Longrightarrow \cos\theta\geq 0$

$\displaystyle 0\leq \theta\leq \frac{\pi}{2}$ or $\displaystyle \frac{3\pi}{2}\leq \theta\leq 2\pi$

Here i did not understand what should i take limit of $\theta$ and $\phi$

Please help me , Thanks

Comment: The integral domain would not give limits on $\theta$ and $\phi$, i.e. $\theta\in[0,2\pi], \phi\in[0,\pi]$.

Comment: Means here $\theta\in[0,2\pi]$ and $\phi\in[0,\pi]$. That what is the use of $x,z\geq 0$

Comment: Your bounds for your triple integral in spherical coordinates will be $$0\leq  \phi <\pi/2$$ $$-\pi/2 < \theta < \pi /2$$ $$3<\rho<4$$ Here, $\phi$ is the angle made with with positive $z$ axis and $\theta$ is the angle made with the positive $x$ axis.

Comment: Thanks so much got it.

Comment: @jacky Oops,sorry. I ignored the condition $x,z\geq 0$ by mistake.